# Always underline mnemonics / keyboard accelerators in LibreOffice under KDE?

Tags: kde, opensuse, gui, libreoffice

I want Alt+Character hotkeys always to be underlined in LibreOffice under KDE (OpenSuse Leap 15.1).

I have configured the GUI theme with "Always show accelerators", but LibreOffice seems to ignore this setting.

I also tried changing "Gnome Application Style" to something other than "Breeze" and restarting LibreOffice, <strike>but it didn't seem to affect the applications at all</strike>*. Also, none of the styles available for GTK3 seem to support underlining accelerators (only oxygen-gtk for GTK2).

[image: se]

### Errata

* Changing the GTK3 style and restarting LibreOffice now works after all. I don't know why it didn't work when I last tried.

Comment: Do you have `libreoffice-kde5` or `libreoffice-qt5` installed?

Comment: @DKBose `zypper` lists `libreoffice-qt5` as installed and cannot find a package containing `libreoffice-kde5`.

Comment: What do you see in *Help > About LibreOffice* in the string after *VCL*?

Comment: @DKBose It says `gtk3_kde5;`. Which seems rather inconsistent with the package name, though I confirmed that the GUI reacts to changing the GTK3 theme. Unlike the KDE them however, the GTK3 themes don't have a configuration interface, where I can select "always show accelerators" for "Breeze", and the configuration for KDE "Breeze" isn't respected apparently.

Comment: What other related package does zypper list? Try having only `libreoffice-qt5` installed. What happens then?

Comment: @DKBose `zypper search -i libreoffice` lists: `libreoffice` 
`libreoffice-base` 
`libreoffice-branding-upstream` 
`libreoffice-calc` 
`libreoffice-calc-extensions` 
`libreoffice-draw` 
`libreoffice-filters-optional` 
`libreoffice-icon-themes` 
`libreoffice-impress` 
`libreoffice-l10n-de` 
`libreoffice-l10n-en`
`libreoffice-mailmerge`
`libreoffice-math`
`libreoffice-pyuno`
`libreoffice-qt5`
`libreoffice-share-linker`
`libreoffice-writer`
`libreoffice-writer-extensions`. I don't have root permissions, so I can't answer the second part of the question without involving the admin.